# Script to download attachment from Equipment in SAP IE03

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a script to download attachments from equipment through "IE03". When I run the command, it runs fine until there is an equipment which does not have an attachment, so I want to skip that and move to next line in loop.

Problem is on this line:

`session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_VIEW_ATTA" )`

Below is the Program

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Define all variables

Dim SapGuiAuto, Application, Connection, session As Object

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

Set Connection = Application.Children(0)

Set session = Connection.Children(0)

Dim i, start_line, finish_line As Integer

start_line = 64

finish_line = 364

' Start processing

For i = start_line To finish_line ' start of loop

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NIE03"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM63E-EQUNR").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"

session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_VIEW_ATTA"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "%ATTA_EXPORT"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\Users\GGC8045\OneDrive - MDLZ\desktop\Chicago 8364\DOCUMENTS"

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 8

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 12

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 12

Cells(i, 5).Value = "Done at " & Now()

Next i ' end of loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can read that sap tag you clicked, it is not the correct one for this question, see if you can find the correct one so that someone specialized in this will be notified.

Comment: A good start would be to tag this in the coding language you're using (VB?). Also, format your code. And from your description of the problem, it sounds like you just need to use a conditional statement to check if the attachment exists. It would be helpful if your code demonstrated your best attempt to do that...

Comment: What is the *specific* "problem" you're having with your code?  What *actually happens* when there's no attachment?

Comment: @TimWilliams
when there is no attachement then this alarm comes "Run-Time Error '619'"


and program stop at here
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"

Comment: @TimWilliams actually i want to download all attachments from all equipment's but some of the equipments dont have attachments and at that location in sap it cannot go to next step

Comment: You can use an error handler to trap that specific error and resume on the next line.  Have you tried that?  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Comment: @TimWilliams yes i tried but may i am making some mistake

Comment: If you post what you tried then folks may have suggestions to fix the issue.  I'm not familiar with using SAP via VBA, so do some of the following lines depend on that problem line being successful?